# Is there a term for when a word is given new meaning with qualifiers?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a qualifier or multiple qualifiers are added to a word to give it a new, related but substantively different meaning, is there a term for that?

Some examples, traffic typically means "cars driving," but qualify it with foot traffic (people walking) or drug traffic (narcotics trade) the word takes on a different meaning.

Holocaust refers to a specific portion of World War 2. Nuclear Holocaust refers to the near or complete annihilation of the human race by nuclear weapons. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_holocaust)

Rock music, initially Rock and Roll which was used to describe the music of the 50s and 60s by pioneers like Chuck Berry and Elvis Presly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_and_roll). The word now typically refers to whichever of the current generation's music offerings are comprised of bass guitar, drums, and rhythm guitar with driving rhythms and strong basslines (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rock+music). However, add some qualifiers and it can be used to describe a number of related, but different genres, such as College Rock (Dave Mathews Band) Indie Rock (Of Monsters and Men) Punk Rock (Pennywise, Guttermouth) Pop-Punk Rock (Fallout Boy, Sugar Cult) Garage Rock (Link Wray, The Animals), ... the list goes on.

Comment: I don't think so, other than maybe Rock vs Rock and Roll, the usage of Holocaust and Traffic is still the same

Comment: I see what your saying, I just don't think it applies because the word itself is not changing, the term only gets a new meaning by adding a qualifier; without the qualifier the term has not changed

Comment: I think they are just different *connotations* of a term: *Holocaust* for instance, carries  different connotations as explained in dictionaries: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/holocaust

Comment: N.B. The World War II Holocaust is traditionally capitalized; other utter destructions by fire are not.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a `clarification`.

Answer (score 0):

We call them *modifiers* for a reason. They modify the word. They modify the meaning.  This is a general feature of English, and not limited to any subset of examples.

- car
- large car
- large blue Ford car
- large blue 1965 Ford car

You could say that each additional modifier adds another level of *qualification*; or, as Vladkornea said, *clarification*.

Answer (score 0):

In each of your examples, the modifier is not actually *necessary* for the resulting meaning. For example, the phrase "traffic out of the building" is attested in reference to people walking out of a building, with no need for *foot*.

So what's going on is that the word has a "default interpretation", which can be overridden by context; with a modifier like *foot* being just one way of providing that overriding context.

You may also be interested in [prototype theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory), which I think explains the "rock" example very well (and perhaps also your other examples): there's a single core type of rock music that's what we think of when we think of "rock", but there are various other kinds of pop music that share enough elements of this core type that they can be referred to as "rock" with appropriate qualification. It's not that the term "rock" has multiple senses for different types of music, it's just that it can be construed more broadly or more narrowly depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that, first, a word denoted a concept, then people started that same word in a broader sense, so people then coined a new term to denote the original meaning? Such a new term is a [retronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym).

[Here](https://www.thoughtco.com/retronym-words-1692051)  is an article giving some examples.

[Here](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/the-top-10-retronyms-a7348411.html) is an article giving some examples (site demands you whitelist the site in order to see the content).